# problems with .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove all the "," within a string with a space. currently I have the following code where tweettxt is simply an array with multiple instances of hello and bye:

```
// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
      split = string.split(" "), // split the string 
      words = {};

  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
      words[split[i]]=1;
    } else {
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}
```

Which returns:

```
{ hello: 50, bye: 36, 'bye,hello': 6 }
```

In an attempt to remove the occurrence of 'bye,hello' I came across and implemented .replace instead of .split on line 4 `split = string.replace(/,/g, "")` however this then returns:

```
{ h: 56, e: 98, l: 112, o: 56, ' ': 91, b: 42, y: 42 }
```

My understanding is that .replace would just replace the , with " " but this is evidently not the case. Can anyone offer any assistance?

EDIT:

code with `.replace`

```
// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
      split = string.replace(/,/g, ""), // split the string 
      words = []; // array for the words

  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
      words[split[i]]=1;
    } else {
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}
```

Comment: `split` returns an array, `replace` returns a string, so you have to adjust your logic accordingly.

Comment: Where exactly did you try to put this `.replace()` code in your code - please show it in place in your question.  `.replace()` operates on a string and returns a new string object.

Comment: Not a good practice to use words like string and split as variable names. Can you not just use tweettxt directly?

Comment: Please show exactly what the input is and what the desired output is.  Your question is not very clear and be very clear about what is a string and what is an object or array.

Comment: I wish to return { hello: 50, bye: 36, 'bye,hello': 6 } without the 'bye,hello' element. The input is stated in the question, simply and array of multiple hello's and bye's, didn't include as it is a long array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string.replace(/,/g, "") just returns the same string (not array) without commas.
Also, if you need to count words based od spaces, you should replace commas with spaces (" ").
So you need to first replace commas and then do split.
E.g.:

```
function getFreqword(){
var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
    sanitizedString = string.replace(/,/g, " "),
    split = sanitizedString.split(" "), // split the string
    words = {};

    for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
        if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
            words[split[i]]=1;
         } else {
            words[split[i]]++;
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: Worded a charm, Thank you